# Удалить дубли в таблице MySQL

Tags: mysql

Необходимо удалить дубли в таблице MySQL, как это делается - не знаю.
Таблица выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строк 2018.

**P. S.:** Это не дубликат [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595072/208074), ибо то решение не подходит, мне нужно удалить дубли только в столбце *image*.

Comment: Это дубликат вопроса. В своём ответе я показал два SQL для частных случаев: если дубликатами надо считать строки по одному полю или по двум.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку данных не очень много, можно просто:

```
DELETE p1 FROM oc_product_image p1, oc_product_image p2 WHERE p1.product_image_id < p2.product_image_id AND p1.product_id = p2.product_id
```

Останутся строки с максимальными product_image_id

Можно еще SELECT DISTINCT'ом сделать INSERT в новую пустую таблицу, сработает быстрее, если база миллионная.

Comment: Дак я вообще хз по поводу максимального product_image_id, он меня не особо интересует.
Меня интересуют строки именно с дублирующимеся ссылками на картинки. 
У них должен быть одинаковый id, потому что это таблица фотографий в карточках товарах OpenCart.

Comment: DELETE p1 FROM oc_product_image p1, oc_product_image p2 WHERE 
p1.image < p2.image AND p1.product_id = p2.product_id

Comment: Т.е. этот запрос удалит дубли только в столбце image?
Ну и соответственно строки, с дублями этими?

Comment: DELETE p1 FROM oc_product_image p1, oc_product_image p2 WHERE p1.product_image_id < p2.product_image_id AND p1.image = p2.image

вот этот удалит строки с одинаковыми полями image
но на всякий случай сделайте бекап, а то мало ли)

Comment: Пред. запрос - оставил лишь дубли :D

Comment: ну да я перепутал поля в сравнении))

Comment: но последний должен норм отработать

Comment: Всем спасибо огромное, дубли выпилились
Новая задачка комрады. 

Есть oc_producte_image и есть oc_product
Айдишники в обоих таблицах соответствуют, а ссылки на картинки в 
oc_product - иные, как сделать что бы пути к картинкам (столбец image) были одинаковым в обоих таблицах

http://skrinshoter.ru/s/041216/wzJgonUs

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто выполнить запрос:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE oc_product_image 
ADD UNIQUE (product_id, image);
```

Мало того, что дубли при его выполнении уберутся (правда, какие из product_image_id удалятся, а какие останутся - неизвестно, но ТС говорит, что ему всё равно), так ещё и в дальнейшем такие дубликаты не появятся - сервер просто не позволит.

Comment: Важный момент - в 5.7.4 alter ignore table удалили, такого способа больше нет.

Comment: Всем спасибо огромное, дубли выпилились
Новая задачка комрады. 

Есть oc_producte_image и есть oc_product
Айдишники в обоих таблицах соответствуют, а ссылки на картинки в 
oc_product - иные, как сделать что бы пути к картинкам (столбец image) были одинаковым в обоих таблицах

http://skrinshoter.ru/s/041216/wzJgonUs

Comment: @ЧуткаПоехавший новые задачки в StackOverflow оформляются новыми вопросами, а не коментериями. И если решение ЭТОГО вопроса подошло, отметьте это галочкой и плюсаните ответившего.